# Image Files are larger than System Partitions when Flashing [remote: size too large] - PixelExperience 13 on Redmi Note 10 (Mojito)

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, redmi, pixel-experience

I'm trying to install PE on my Redmi Note 10 and am having trouble with fastboot flashing.

I´ve already unlocked bootloader and USB Debugging is enabled.

The problem appears when trying to flash 'vendor_boot' and 'boot' partitions, in all cases the images sizes are bigger than the partitions throwing me this:

```
PS C:\Users\domen\adb-fastboot\platform-tools> ./fastboot flash boot_b PixelExperience_Plus_mojito-13.0-20231217-1954-OFFICIAL.img
Warning: skip copying boot_b image avb footer (boot_b partition size: 67108864, boot_b image size: 134217728).
Sending 'boot_b' (131072 KB)                       OKAY [  3.124s]
Writing 'boot_b'                                   FAILED (remote: 'size too large')
fastboot: error: Command failed
PS C:\Users\domen\adb-fastboot\platform-tools> ./fastboot flash vendor_boot_b vendor_boot.img
Warning: skip copying vendor_boot_b image avb footer (vendor_boot_b partition size: 67108864, vendor_boot_b image size: 100663296).
Sending 'vendor_boot_b' (98304 KB)                 OKAY [  2.338s]
Writing 'vendor_boot_b'                            FAILED (remote: 'size too large')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

I already tested the legacy partition (its the B).

If anyone could give me any solutions i'll really appreciate it

Comment: Just to make sure, were you following [the guide](https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/mojito/install/)?

Comment: Yeah, I did every step from that guide. And got stuck on the vendor_boot flashing step. And for me with no reason... But I do have my suspicious with the adb/fastboot setup that I'm using. I'll try to do it on another pc and check out